# Is \tkzDrawVector(s) from tkz-euclide working?

Tags: tkz-euclide

Is is just me or is `\tkzDrawVector(s)` from `tkz-euclide` package not working at all?

Interestingly enough `\tkzDefVector` works perfectly well. :)

For instance the example from p.155 of the manual: http://mirrors.concertpass.com/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tkz/tkz-euclide/doc/tkz-euclide-screen.pdf

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5]
\tkzDefPoint(1,1){A}
\tkzDefPoint(8,0){B}
\tkzDefPoint(3,4){C}
\tkzDefVector[colinear= at C](A,B){D}
\tkzDrawVectors[color=blue](A,B A,C)
\tkzDrawVector[color=red](A,D)
\tkzLabelPoints(A,B,C,D)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Causes:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.10 \tkzDrawVectors
                    [color=blue](A,B A,C)
?
```

Comment: Add `\usetkzobj{all}` to the preamble.

Comment: Worked. Thank you.
I understand why.
Thanks one more time.